# Разделение body на части

Tags: html

Я хочу спросить, как разбить тег `body` на классы, чтобы в теге `<style>` применить к одной части текста один стиль, а к другой - другой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body - корневой еллемент отображаемой части html документа, ваш вопрос некоректен...
По поводу частей именно текста - схема такая же как привел **deamondz**, только вместо тега *div* используем *span* 
Например:

```
<style type="tex/css">
   .red {color:red}
   .bold {font-weight:bold}
   .italic {font-style:italic}
</style>
<span class="red">
        Красный текст
    <span class="bold">
        тут еще и жирный
    </span>
    <span class="italic">
        а тут курсив
    </span>
</span>
```

PS:естественно пример абстрактный и стили могут быть описаны как угодно

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<body>
<div class="class_1">content</div>
<div class="class_2">content</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.class_1{anystyle:any_property}
.class_2{anystyle:any_property}
```